# Rename multiple files by using BATCH, VBSCRIPT or BASH SHELL

Tags: bash, vbscript, batch-file

I have a numbers of files in folder A, what I need to do is to rename the filename to different pattern example: `TTFILE-201109265757.dat` to `YTL.MSZSH1.ch1.201109265757_0001.0001.dat`

Where **YTL, MSZSH1, ch1** is prefix then follow by the filename then `_` then sequence number

The filename pattern should be like this:  `YTL.MSZSH1.ch1.filename_SequenceNumber.SequenceNumber` where `SequenceNumber` is 4 digit, reset to 0 after 9999.

Comment: Why doesn't `TTFILE-` appear in the new name?

Answer (score 2):

This little bash script should do the work :) Just call it with the files in question in the argument list or replace `$@` with `$(ls)`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
counter=1
prefix="YTL.MSZSH1.ch1."
for i in "$@" ; do
    file=$(basename "$i")
    counter=$(printf "%04d" $counter)
    mv "$i" "$prefix${file/TTFILE-/}_$counter.$counter.dat"
    counter=$(( $counter+1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows environment, here is the script I would run:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1

set c=0
for /r %%i in ( %2-*.dat ) do (
  set filename=%%~ni
  set digits=!filename:%2-=!
  ren "%%i" %3.%4.%5.!digits!_!c.!c!.dat
  set /a c+=1
  if !c! equ 10000 set c=0
)

popd
```

To run it: `script.cmd "D:\Test Area" TTFILE YTL MSZSH1 ch1`, where `D:\Test Area` is the directory containing the `.dat` files and the following arguments are the prefixes to use.

If `D:\Test Area` contains sub-directories, the `.dat` files contained in them will also be renamed, but the sequence number will not be reset between two different sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way in vbscript

```
    Dim objFSO,myFolder,objFolder,colFiles,objFile,newName,i,n
    set sh=createobject("wscript.shell")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    myFolder = "C:\users\eng\desktop\Scripts"    '' here you can write the path for your folder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myFolder)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    i=0:n="0000"
    For Each objFile in colFiles
     if Not instr(1,objFile.name,"YTL.MSZSH1.ch1.",1) > 0 then  ''check if the file name change.this step to avoid change file name again after we rename

    newName=replace(objFile.Name,"TTFILE-","YTL.MSZSH1.ch1.")   ''replace "TTFILE-" with "YTL.MSZSH1.ch1." in the file name
    newName=replace(newName,right(newName,4),"_"&n&"."&n&".dat")   ''replace in modefiy newName ".dat" to "_0000.0000.dat" in the file name

    objFSO.getfile(objFile).name=newName    ''change the file name with newName
    sh.popup objfile,1,"In_The_Name_Of_Allah"

    i=i+1

       If i < 10 Then
            n= CStr("000" & i)
        ElseIf i < 100 Then
            n= CStr("00" & i)
        ElseIf i < 1000 Then
            n= CStr("0" & i)
        Else
            n= i
        End If
    End If
Next
wscript.quit
```